# Font Size Changer

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, font-size

I'm designing a website using bootstrap that requires me to use font resize. I tried to do it with some javascript and jquery. The script runs but the font size wasnt responding. How can I make it work and how can i use the !important in these javascript.

```
$(".decreaseFont").click(function(){
var currentFontSize = $('html').css('font-size');
var currentFontSizeNum = parseFloat(currentFontSize, 10);
var newFontSize = currentFontSizeNum*0.8;
$('html').css('font-size', newFontSize);
return false;
```

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/LHzBS/1/ works ok :o

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is working.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/LHzBS/1

Maybe it is the other code in the file has errors. You can use a web console to debug, use:

```
debugger;
```

to add breakpoints.

Answer (score 0):

could be that the browser you are testing in does not automatically assume pixels as the unit. To be safe change the last line to this

```
$('html').css('font-size', newFontSize+'px')
```

Comment: You don't have to do that. jQuery will do that for you.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go: http://jsfiddle.net/toadkicker/NJUH7/

Answer (score 0):

Here you can Increase or Decrease the size of text by Clicking on + or - Signs http://jsfiddle.net/ipsjolly/hzD8h/1/